# How to convert TableForm to proper LaTex and why is "\" not replaced by StringReplace?

Tags: string-manipulation, latex

I'm trying to optimize the teXForm output of a table because the standard output ist not satisfying:

```
badLatex = TeXForm[TableForm[{
{"nm", "E1", "E2"},
{500.`, -0.001`, -0.001`},
{499.`, -0.001`, 0.`},
{498.`, 0.`, -0.001`}}]]
```

I get this output

```
\begin{array}{ccc}
     \text{nm} & \text{E} & \text{E} \\
     500. & -0.001 & -0.001 \\
     499. & -0.001 & 0. \\
     498. & 0. & -0.001 \\
    \end{array}
```

No I want to replace the decimal points with commas, change the environment and eliminate the "\text" command. The last doesn't work for me.

```
goodLatex = StringReplace[ToString[badLatex],
    {"array" -> "tabular","." -> "," ,  "\text" -> ""}]
```

I get the following result:

```
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
         \text{nm} & \text{E1} & \text{E2} \\
         500, & -0,001 & -0,001 \\
         499, & -0,001 & 0, \\
         498, & 0, & -0,001 \\
    \end{tabular}
```

As you can see, the expression "\text" is still there. Why is "\" not replaced by StringReplace?
Do you have a better idea how to convert tables to proper LaTex code?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Mathematica, as well as many other programming languages (C, Java, Python, etc.), a two-character sequence of the form `\x`, where `x` may be anything, *represents a single character in the string*.  This is just a notational convention that allows us to enter characters that would otherwise be impossible to include in a string.  This notation is called *escape sequences*.

Examples: `"\""` is a single character string containing `"`.  The -notation makes it possible to include a " sign in a string delimited using the same character.  Other common escape sequences: `"\n"` is a newline, `"\r"` is a carriage return, `"\t"` is a tab, etc.

To enter a string containing `\`, you need to use the notation `"\\"`.  So your `StringReplace` will need to have `"\\text" -> ""`.

Answer (score 2):

In *Mathematica* strings `\` is an escape character.  Try:

```
StringReplace[ToString[badLatex], {"array" -> "tabular", "." -> ",", "\\text" -> ""}]
```

Also, you say "proper LaTeX code" but the original "badLatex" string is recognized here as:

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{nm} & \text{E1} & \text{E2} \\
 500. & -0.001 & -0.001 \\
 499. & -0.001 & 0. \\
 498. & 0. & -0.001
\end{array}$

which seems alright to me.